# Are those white things in my lentil soup worms?

Tags: soup

[image]

I just made this soup but I noticed these white things in it are they worms?

Comment: What ingredients did you use?  There are a lot of white things for you to have missed them when adding ingredients, so it would be surprising if you did so

Comment: Just lentils and onions

Comment: Did you soak the lentils for a while before cooking?  These look like [sprouted lentils](https://www.healthbenefitstimes.com/9/uploads/2018/07/Sprouted-Lentils.jpg) to me.

Answer (score 4):

Those look to be radicles (embryonic stems, the part the root grows from) that have separated from the lentils. If you look closely at the less squished lentils in your soup, you'll probably see some with the radicles still attached.